# Reload Signer Lamport balance in Anchor

Tags: anchor, rust

How can we reload the lamport balance of a Signer to compare before/after a CPI?

If we have:

```
pub struct SomeIX<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
//etc...
```

and in our handler:

```
    let lamports_before = ctx.accounts.payer.lamports();
    //Some CPI where payer pays...
    //RELOAD?
    let lamports_after = ctx.accounts.payer.lamports();
```

For Token accounts, we can simply do: `ctx.accounts.some_acc.reload()?;`

But Signer has no reload function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is actually that the lamport balance updates automatically. For example when using the system program to transfer funds, the lamport balance will be updated after the CPI.

Lamports should be borrowed as mut.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried accessing the `account_info` using `ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info().lamports()` and seeing if that contains the updated value?

Comment: It's entirely possible this doesn't work but I presume there's a reason anchor doesn't have a `reload` function for regular account types